# How can I skip character encoding errors when importing a text file into MySQL?

Tags: c#, mysql

Trying to import large text files into MySQL with this:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '\\\\myfile.csv'
INTO TABLE R_Delta_Previous 
-- CHARACTER SET utf8
-- CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
  ENCLOSED BY '"'
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

The table collation is set to utf8mb4 as are all the text columns. However, one of the lines is choking on an illegal character:

```
Error Code: 1300. Invalid utf8mb4 character string: '"Rg12'
```

Now, the trouble is that this is going to be an ongoing issue. We're going to be getting a lot of these text files and I have no faith that provider can find and fix these issues upfront. Fixing the file is not an option: I have to fix the import.

I've also tried loading it with C# using the `MySqlBulkLoader` class which throws the same exception. Unsurprising given that it wraps the `INFILE` command. Adding either of those commented out `CHARACTER SET` statements doesn't help either.

I don't care if I lose the data containing the illegal characters. Is there any way I can force MySql to ignore the error, skip the line, and carry on processing?